# зачем нужны фреймворки?

Tags: веб-программирование

Кто нибудь может объяснить кратко и ясно зачем они нужны?

Comment: Фреймворк - набор готовых функций, процедур и многого другого, создан для того, чтобы избавить программиста от рутиной работы.

Comment: тру проггерам фреймворки не нужны. только самопис, только хардкор!

Comment: Зачем они нужны понятно из любого материала, где даётся формулировка этому термину. Может вы расширите вопрос, выскажите мнение, если считаете что они не нужны? Или в чём собственно суть вопроса?

Comment: @pavel1787mego вы путаете фреймворки с IDE. Это совершенно разные вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб не писать свой код, используешь фреймовики, написанные профессионалами(или нет). Тебе не придется самостоятельно и с нуля писать какие-либо сложные вещи, тк есть люди, которые уже сделали это до тебя и делятся своими разработками с миром.

Answer (score 5):

Они **повышают уровень абстракции доступных технических средств**.

Всякий раз, когда вы решаете какую-то задачу некими техническими средствами, вы выстраиваете абстракции от *доступных технических средств (низкий уровень)* до *сущностей решаемой задачи (высокий уровень)*. Между ними получается некая **разность высот**, которую ваше решение должно замостить. И чем эта разность больше, тем больше кода потребуется на её покрытие.

Фреймворки уменьшают эту **разность высот** путём предоставления средств более высокого уровня. Разность высот меньше —> кода меньше [—> багов меньше].

---

*В чём подвох?* Ну... зависит от многих факторов.

Их средства обычно имеют свою стоимость в производительности, поскольку они не специализируются на именно вашем случае. Из-за этого, не спускаясь на уровни пониже, можно запросто нахватать неоптимальных решений и получить не такой производительный результат, какой можно было бы. Или кода может выйти не меньше, если ваша задача вне области фреймворка.

С другой стороны, в фреймворки обычно вложено больше человекочасов, чем в решения, которые вы можете написать сами. И в них могли уже решить немало проблем (в том числе с производительностью) с которыми вы сами ещё не сталкивались. Поэтому ситуация может получиться обратной: не имея достаточного опыта, вы можете написать своё специализированное решение, *уступающее* по эффективности решению фреймворком.